# Symfony2 registerBundles()

Tags: php, symfony

I am really trying to learn this new framework but tutorials are really  hard to come by, I'm trying to follow a blog one [here](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/configuration-and-templating.html) but seem to get getting the same errors.

**Error**

> Bundle "BloggerBlogBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe
>   you forgot to add it in the registerBundles() method of your
>   AppKernel.php file?

**My routing looks like this →**

```
# src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml
BloggerBlogBundle_homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: BloggerBlogBundle:Page:index }
    requirements:
        _method:  GET
```

**AppKernel.php**

```
 public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(

            new Blogger\BlogBundle\BlogBundle(),
        );
```

Thanks

Comment: Please read documentation carefully http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/configuration-and-templating.html#registering-the-bundle. There is: `new Blogger\BlogBundle\BloggerBlogBundle()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **AppKernel.php** should probably look like this

```
public function registerBundles(){
        $bundles = array(
             new Blogger\BlogBundle\BloggerBlogBundle(),
        );
}
```